# How to solve this equation for x (May require product log or Lambert-W function)

Tags: exponential-function, lambert-w

I need help solving the following for t (by hand):

$$
A=Bt+Ce^{Dt}
$$
where A, B, C, and D are constants.

Is this possible? I'm guessing the Lambert-W function is required.

Thank you

Comment: The solution to this is given at the end of [example 1](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lambert_W_function#Example_1).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If $A-Bt = s$, so $t = A/B - s/B$, the equation becomes 
$$ s = C \exp(AD/B - Ds/B)$$
i.e.
$$ s \exp(Ds/B) = C \exp(AD/B) $$
and then with $u = Ds/B$, 
$$ u \exp(u) = \dfrac{CD}{B} \exp(AD/B)$$
So we have $$u = W\left( \dfrac{CD}{B} \exp\left(\frac{AD}{B}\right)\right)$$
i.e.
$$ t = \dfrac{A}{B} - \dfrac{1}{D} W\left(\dfrac{CD}{B} \exp\left(\frac{AD}{B}\right)\right)$$
where $W$ is any branch of the Lambert W function.